# Property 'LastName' does not exist on type 'HomeComponent'

Tags: typescript, angular8

I am getting Error : **Property 'LastName' does not exist on type 'HomeComponent'** would like to know how to implement interface into ngoninit

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ProviderDataService } from '../Shared/Services/retriveProviderData.service'

export interface IProviderDatas
{
  LastName: string;
  FirstName: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  provider : IProviderDatas[];
  constructor(private providerdataservice : ProviderDataService) {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.providerdataservice.return_providerData().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.LastName = data[0].LastName
        this.FirstName = data[0].FirstName
      }
  )
  }

}
```

Comment: `LastName` and `FirstName` are defined on `IProviderDatas` why do you expect them to exist on `this` (which is the `HomeComponent `)

Comment: If i remove this, then its error as "cannot find LastName".
If i "provider.LastName" then its error as Cannot find name 'provider'. Did you mean the instance member 'this.provider'?

Comment: But `provider` is an array of `IProviderDatas`. You could do `this.provider.push(data[0])` or `this.provider[0].LastName = data[0].LastName` (providing the array is initialized suitably)  but more likely you want `this.provider = data` to set the data with the array that comes from the request .. but I am just guessing your intentions here..

Comment: "you want this.provider = data to set the data with the array that comes from the request". Yes. I want this only. within provider interface i want to set the data. As the data can be of 'n' number of records (which is json format) i need to put this n number of records inside IProviderdatas. Looking forward your help

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `FirstName` and `LastName` members of the class.

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  public FirstName;
  public LastName

  provider : IProviderDatas[];
  constructor(private providerdataservice : ProviderDataService) {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.providerdataservice.return_providerData().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.LastName = data[0].LastName
        this.FirstName = data[0].FirstName
      }
  )
  }

}
```

But be careful. If you want to use it in the template, it will throw `undefined` error because they are assigned values **after** `return_providerData` observable emits a value.

In order to avoid it, you can use `async` pipe in your template instead of manually subscribing.